# Using tikz with both tex4ht and pdflatex

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex4ht

I found that in order to use tikz with tex4ht to produce HTML, I need to do the following:

```
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-tex4ht.def}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

I also need to produce PDF from the same tex file using pdflatex, but that gives me an error with the `\def` above.

Is there a way to exclude the `def` from pdflatex?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`htlatex` loads package `tex4ht` at the end of the class. Therefore `\@ifpackageloaded` can be used to detect TeX4ht. Inside a class `tex4ht` is not yet loaded if `htlatex` is used. Then TeX4ht can be detected via `\HCode` that is defined by `htlatex`.

```
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}{%
  \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-tex4ht.def}%
}{%
  % only needed inside a class
  \begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\ifx\csname HCode\endcsname\relax
  \else
    \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-tex4ht.def}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{tikz}
```

Comment: Works great - thanks! One question, @Heiko - where can I learn these tex programming commands? Is _The TexBook_ by Knuth the right place? Right now, the only book I have is _The Latex Companion_.

Comment: Experience, answering bug reports, the stuff with `\HCode` was a recent addition to `hyperref`, ...